# AMD/ATI Radeon HD 6670 Graphics are Very Laggy in 13.10

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon, fglrx

It's very unfortunate because it really degrades the Ubuntu experience compared to Windows Vista.

A year ago I bought an AMD/ATI Radeon HD 6670 graphic card because my old Nvidia card was getting too old for Windows 8 and Ubuntu. But when I retried Ubuntu with this newer card, I had a display problem. So I switched back to Windows and waited, telling myself that it would get solved in a future update from the community.

This update finally came between 13.04 and 13.10. The open source drivers could finally make Ubuntu look like Ubuntu instead of a purple screen... But the open source drivers are very, very laggy. So much that I can't handle browsing any web page with Firefox. What feel snappy, surprisingly, are the cursor, the launcher and the dash. So I searched on the Web and found instructions about switching to fglrx and fglrx-updates. Man, you can't know how much this frustrated me. I had to reinstall Ubuntu at least 10 times just because of these graphics. I couldn't see any login screen. So I waited for another update.

Now, one year later I can finally use fglrx and fglrx-updates. However, to my great surprise... it's even laggier than the open source driver!?

I swear it has nothing to do with my graphics card being not fast enough. In Windows Vista, everything is snappy. In fact, my seven years-old laptop with integrated Intel graphics fares better.

What should I do? For now, my only solution seems to stay with Windows...

Comment: I have tried running the automatic installation from AMD's website, but I got errors in the installation log : http://justpaste.it/dyxz

Answer (score 1):

Up until a few weeks ago I had an HD5670 for my 13.10 install. I downloaded and installed the driver direct from AMD's website and had better performance than from any of the ones listed in Additional Drivers (in fact, AMD just released a driver update on 12/19/13).

Comment: Interesting. I'm rebooting into Ubuntu and I'm going to take a look at the direct drivers you're talking about. I hope it's not going to make my distro unusable again...

Comment: I ran the automatic installation for my graphics card, but at the end of the process it alerted me that there were errors during the installation and to check in the installation log.

Here is the content of the log : http://justpaste.it/dyxz

Answer (score 0):

I have asked for help in the IRC channel, and a user (Pessimist) helped be generously to switch back to the open source graphics and to switch to the PPA : https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers

For now it seems to be better now. Only thing left is to see how I can make scrolling in Firefox a tad smoother...